How to wrap if condition in then function in javascript?
i am new to learning javascript. i am currently trying to wrap if condition inside a then function.
below is my code,
const createType = ({
    firstTypes = [],
    secondTypes = [],
    ...allType
    } = {}, skip = true) => {
    const builtType = buildType(allType);
    let finalType;
    let finalSecondTypes;

    return apiPostType(builtType)
    .then(waitForSync(cy.apiGetTypeWithRetry))
    .then(createdType => {
    finalType = keysToCamelCase(createdType);
    const firstTypesToCreate = firstTypes.map(
        firstType => () =>
        cy.createFirstType({
            ...firstType,
            allType: createdType.id,
        })
    );

the above code works fine. now i want to execute waitForSync(apiGetTypeWithRetry) only if skip is set to false. hence i tried like below,
const createType = ({
    firstTypes = [],
    secondTypes = [],
    ...allType
    } = {}, skip = true) => {
    const builtType = buildType(allType);
    let finalType;
    let finalSecondTypes;

    return apiPostType(builtType)
    .then(() => { 
        if(!skip) {
            waitForSync(cy.apiGetTypeWithRetry);
        }
    })
    .then(createdType => { //here createdType is undefined
    finalType = keysToCamelCase(createdType);
    const firstTypesToCreate = firstTypes.map(
        firstType => () =>
        cy.createFirstType({
            ...firstType,
            allType: createdType.id,
        })
    );

but after adding if condition in the .then() function the createdType for the next .then() function is undefined.
so then i tried like below
return apiPostType(builtType)
    .then(createdType => { //but this complains of being 
        "variable defined but never used"
        if(!skip) {
            waitForSync(cy.apiGetTypeWithRetry);
        }
     })
     .then(createdType => { //still undefined
         finalType = keysToCamelCase(createdType);
         const firstTypesToCreate = firstTypes.map(
             firstType => () => 
                 //some logic
         });

it is still undefined for the .then function
i am not sure how to pass the promise from the previous .then function.
could someone help me with this. thanks.

if (skip = false) is probably a typo for (!skip) or (skip === false)

In the second then(createdType => the createdType is the result of the previous then, but the previous then didn't produce any result (no return statement). But I don't see why you need a second then anyway. Just combine the two.

(Also, your first version doesn't do what you think.)

could you post an answer to this @Raymond Chen. thanks

@Harika please edit your question and fix the skip = false problems if they're just typos, because it's very distracting.

its edited now @Wyck

The condition if (skip = false) should use a comparison operator (===) instead of an assignment operator (=). It should be if (skip === false) or simply if (!skip) for better readability.
We can conditionally append the waitForSync(cy.apiGetTypeWithRetry) promise to the promiseChain only if skip is false.
Then we can return the promiseChain from the createType function to ensure that subsequent .then() handlers receive the resolved value correctly.
The eslint error "variable createdType defined but never used" will be resolved because createdType is now used in the subsequent .then() handler.
Like this:
    let promiseChain = apiPostType(builtType);

    if (!skip) {
        promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => waitForSync(cy.apiGetTypeWithRetry));
    }

    return promiseChain.then(createdType => {
        finalType = keysToCamelCase(createdType);
        const firstTypesToCreate = firstTypes.map(
            firstType => () =>
            //some logic
        );
    });

